# c# Binary Serialization output size

Tags: c#, serialization

The output string of the BinarySerializer seems too long. It does not change even if I shorten the property names of the class to single character length.

Here is the class file:

```
using System;

namespace Models.Accounts
{
    /// <summary>
    /// PasswordResetRequest class
    /// model of a password reset request
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class PRR
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// request id
        /// </summary>
        public string I { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// time request received
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime T { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// application to which the password belongs
        /// </summary>
        public string A { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// username whose password needs to be reset
        /// </summary>
        public string U { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// token (guid)
        /// </summary>
        public Guid G { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// token used
        /// </summary>
        public bool D { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// client ip
        /// </summary>
        public string C { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I'm using [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861749) for serialization. When I use the serializer as

```
        PRR request = new PRR();
        request.U = "someusername";
        request.G = Guid.NewGuid();

        string searlizedRequest = SingletonCommon.Instance.SerializeObject(request);
```

I get a very long value for `searlizedRequest` like `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`

Is there any formatter with shorter output I can use or anything else I can try, since this string will be part of a link sent in an email.

Comment: Use protobuf-net instead if you want a small result

Comment: I'd put this data in a DB and send the user a small key to that information.

Comment: If you need just *any* serialization, then use `XmlSerializer`. You can control it with attributes and files can be edited/viewed by a human (xml is easy to understand). If you need minimum size, then you have to use binary serialization: `BinarySerializer`, [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) (fastests, smallest, not human viewable/editable and required using third-party library, though very well supported). If your aim is to transfer serialized object via ascii-text channel, then why not using [json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx), designed specially?

Comment: @jgauffin thanks- trying protobuf-net now (though skeptical of continued .net support).
usr- good idea - thanks will try that too
Sinatr- can't use xml or json since this is a password reset link that is going to user's email. should not be *easily* decodable

Comment: Converted properties to fields and used `[NonSerializable]` attribute for some fields, and it reduced the size by almost 40%. Not bad for right now

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try `GZipStream` to compress the output when writing to a file to have minimum size

```cs
public static void SetCompressed<T>(T data,string name) 
{
    BinaryFormatter bf;
    using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(name+ ".object", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using(GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        bf.Serialize(compressionStream, data);
    }
}

public static T GetCompressed<T>(string name) 
{
    BinaryFormatter bf;
    T Tobject;
    using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(name + ".object", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using(GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        Tobject = (T)bf.Deserialize(compressionStream);
    }

    return Tobject;
}
```

The code above uses `BinaryFormatter` to serialize any object alongwith `FileStream` & `GZipStream`. The `GZipStream` will compress the output ***.object** file to some extent.

> **HACK**: You  can open the the ***.object** file with **7-Zip** to see the serialized content inside.

Comment: ended up implementing @usr comment.

Comment: The case against `Base64` is it encodes strings as `UTF-8` first, and then encodes the resulting byte sequence as `Base64`. So it will increase by 30 -33%.