# C# issue with deserializing text file to list box, pulling all lines

Tags: c#, serialization

I can put the whole code if needed, I have only added the save and load buttons. I have a load button that is supposed to take serialized data from a file and deserialize it into a listbox. The problem I am having is when I deserialize it, I have only figured out how to get the first line to pull. Tried using a while statement and it only brought in the last line of the file. I am guessing I am using the wrong parameters in the while statement. I commented out the while statement and the {}.

```
    // event handler for save case button
    private void saveCaseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // store TextBox values string array
        string[] values = GetTextBoxValues();

        // Record containing TextBox values to serialize
        RecordSerializable record = new RecordSerializable();

        // determine whether TextBox name field is empty
        if (values[(int)TextBoxIndices.NAME] != string.Empty)
        {
            // store TextBox values in Record and serialize Record
            try
            {
                // get studentID value from TextBox
                int studentID = Int32.Parse(
                   values[(int)TextBoxIndices.STUDENTID]);

                // determine whether studentID is valid
                if (studentID > 0)
                {
                    // store TextBox fields in Record
                    record.StudentID = studentID;
                    record.Name = values[(int)
                       TextBoxIndices.NAME];
                    record.Grade = values[(int)
                       TextBoxIndices.GRADE];

                    // create string out of record fields
                    nextCase = (record.Name + ", " + record.StudentID + ", " +
                       record.Grade);

                    // add line to list box
                    listBox1.Items.Add(nextCase);

                    // write Record to file, fields separated by commas
                    //fileWriter.WriteLine(nextCase);

                    // write Record to FileStream ( serialize object )
                    formatter.Serialize(output, record);

                } // end if
                else
                {
                    // notify user if invalid account number
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Student ID", "Error",
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                } // end else
            } // end try
            // notify user if error occurs in serialization
            catch (SerializationException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Writing to File", "Error",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            } // end catch

            catch (IOException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Writing to File", "Error",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                MessageBox.Show("Error in saveCaseButton_Click \n" + nextCase + "\n" + fileName);
            } // end catch
            // notify user if error occurs regarding parameter format
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Format", "Error",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            } // end catch
        } // end if

        ClearTextBoxes(); // clear TextBox values


    } // end saveCaseButton_Click

    // event handler for load file button
    private void loadFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create and show dialog box enabling user to open file         
        DialogResult result; // result of OpenFileDialog

        using (OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
            fileName = fileChooser.FileName; // get specified name
        } // end using

        // ensure that user clicked "OK"
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ClearTextBoxes();

            // show error if user specified invalid file
            if (fileName == string.Empty)
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid File Name", "Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else
            {
                // create FileStream to obtain read access to file
                input = new FileStream(
                    fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read );

                nameTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
                studentIDTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
                gradeTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
                createFileButton.Enabled = false;
                saveCaseButton.Enabled = false;
                closeFileButton.Enabled = false;
            } // end else
        } // end if

        // deserialize Record and store data in TextBoxes
        try
        {
            //read all data from file
            //while ((RecordSerializable)reader.Deserialize(input) != null)
            //{

            // get next RecordSerializable available in file
            RecordSerializable record =
               (RecordSerializable)reader.Deserialize(input);

            // store Record values in temporary string array
            string[] values = new string[] 
            {
                record.Name.ToString(),
                record.StudentID.ToString(),
                record.Grade.ToString()
            }; // end string[] values

            // copy string array values to TextBox values
            SetValuesToListBox(values);
            //} // end while

        } // end try
        // handle exception when there are no Records in file
        catch (SerializationException)
        {
            input.Close(); // close FileStream if no Records in file
            nameTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
            studentIDTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
            gradeTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
            createFileButton.Enabled = false;
            saveCaseButton.Enabled = false;
            closeFileButton.Enabled = false;

            ClearTextBoxes();

            // notify user if no Records in file
            MessageBox.Show("No more records in file", string.Empty,
               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        } // end catch


    } // end loadFileButton_Click
```

Comment: Is RecordSerializable only one record? How is the data serialized? If that code works the file only contains one record.

Comment: @Rinecamo When the data is serialized it is put into one line of a text document and it looks like it is separated by "   ÿÿÿÿ". Would it be more beneficial if I added the full code?

Comment: Since I don't know how the data is serialized exactly I can only guess, so try the following: Read every line of the textfile (StreamReader, File.ReadAllLines, etc.) and deserialize it with the second method in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2861749/4993632 Then every line is one record.

Comment: @rinecamo I added the code for the save button

Comment: Ignore my last comment then, gonna try something, I answer when I'm finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, try the following:

```
while (input.Position < input.Length) {
    var record = (RecordSerializable)formatter.Deserialize(input);
    string[] values = new string[] 
    {
        record.Name.ToString(),
        record.StudentID.ToString(),
        record.Grade.ToString()
    }; // end string[] values

        // copy string array values to TextBox values
    SetValuesToListBox(values);
}
```

The list should contain all serialized objects.

Comment: Thank you for that, I am still a little new to programming, where should that go in my code and do I need to remove anything?